# Need to ignore bootstrap modal validation in form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a form with validations and I have a modal inside with it owns validations. When I open the modal and close it without filling any data, the form gets an invalid, so I can't submit the form. It's like the validations on the modal invalidates my form.

**What I need is that the modal and form validations be done separately**

My code:

```
$().ready(function () {
   moment.locale('es');
   $('form').validate({
      ignore: "",
      rules: {
        'SolicitudVacaciones.SolicitanteNombreUsuario': { required: true },
        'SolicitudVacaciones.SolicitudFecha': { required: true, argentinianDate: true },
        'SolicitudVacaciones.LicenciaId': { required: true, numero: true },
        'SolicitudVacaciones.PeriodoVacaciones': { required: true, numero: true },
        'SolicitudVacaciones.LimiteDiasPeriodo': { required: true, numero: true },
        'SolicitudVacaciones.DiasDispPeriodo': { required: true, numero: true },
        'SolicitudVacaciones.SolicitudEstadoId': { required: true, numero: true }
     } //end validation rules
   });
   $('#mdlSolicitudVacaciones').validate({
     rules: {
        'txtDíassolicitados11': { required: true, numero: true },
        'dtFechadesde11': {
            required: true,
            argentinianDate: true
        },
        'dtFechahasta13': {
            required: true,
            argentinianDate: true
        },
        'dtFechareincorporación14': {
            required: true,
            argentinianDate: true
        }
     }
  });
});



<input type="submit" id="btnAceptar" class="btn btn-blue" data-role="none" value="@Resources.Resource.btnAceptar" onclick="return sendForm();" />
```

Notice that in the "sendForm()" method, there's a 
`if (!$('form').valid()) return bState;` and it becames false when done what I explained

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! Think it would help if you add more code... Please read the guideline on how to ask a good question -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is by referring to `form` you are validating ALL forms.

CHANGE
`$('form').validate({`

to the ID of the specific form that it is meant to validate